# Can I run an Executable Haskell file from Python?

Tags: python-3.x, haskell, cabal

I have a Haskell Executable (by using the build command from cabal) which I call through a command in a terminal, the command being

`cabal run CSVTest`

The command needs to be run in the base directory of the Tool (in this case I run the terminal from /home/dayiz/ConfigV where a ConfigV.Cabal file is located where I give information on the executable files)
This gives an output in the console which I want to evaluate in Python. (If you are curious where this comes from, I'm trying to use the output from ConfigV https://github.com/ConfigV/ConfigV to correct configuration files)

Is it possible to give the location of the file and run it inside a Python?
The general idea is to run my python tool, decide with which tool you want to check your file (in this case we use ConfigV to verify the file. The user would have to give the path to his Haskell executable which he needs to prepare before), run the tool and get the the output, then act on it in python again.

Most solutions i found online don't seem to work in my case, since im not just executing a haskell skript. The file needs to be build beforehand with cabal and I couldn't find anything for my specific case. ChatGPT gave me some lines of code

```
    import subprocess
    haskell_executable = '/home/dayiz/ConfigV/Executables/CSVTest.hs'

    try:
        subprocess.run([haskell_executable], check=True)
    except subprocess.CalledProcessError as e:
        print(f"Error running Haskell executable: {e}")
```

but when I try to use it I get
OSError: [Errno 8] Exec format error: /home/dayiz/ConfigV/Executables/CSVTest.hs and I'm just lost at this point.

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't you need to actually call cabal here with the filepath as the argument? I think subprocess is trying to basically call a file path.

https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html

Looking at the docs I think you want something like this? (the `capture_output` flag is if you want to do something with the output of the script).

```
subprocess.run(["cabal", "run", "/home/dayiz/ConfigV/Executables/CSVTest.hs"], capture_output=True)
```

Comment: This almost solved my problem. You are right about adding "cabal" and "run" to run(), but then it still wouldn't work since cabal expected an executable declared in ConfigV.cabal
I managed to get it working by using the parameter cwd and assigned it to the right directory. the line that works looks like this:
`subprocess.run(["cabal", "run", "CSVTest"], capture_output=True, cwd="/home/dayiz/ConfigV")`
Thank you very much :)

Answer (score 0):

The best solution depends on what kind of project this is.

The easiest option is to just *install* the executable with `cabal install`, which will put it in `~/.cabal/bin`. If you have that in you your `$PATH` (may need to say so, e.g. in your `.bashrc` file), then you can simply use

```
subprocess.run(["CSVTest"], capture_output=True)
```

I'm assuming you have a section

```
executable CSVTest
  main-is:             CSVTest.hs
  hs-source-dirs:      Executables
  build-depends:       ...
```

in you `ConfigV.cabal` file.

This is of course pretty horrible from a Continuous Integration perspective. (But if your Python ecosystem [looks anything like mine](https://xkcd.com/1987/), then CI is out of the question anyway...)

If you want the code to be somewhat contained, you should not globally install anything. You could call `cabal run` as a standin for "your Haskell executable", but that's pretty inefficient if you call it multiple times, since each of them needs to fire up Cabal which has to do all its dependency checking etc..

A better solution is to pre-compile the Haskell code and use that without invoking any compilation from Python. In fact the best way to do this is to only compile the Haskell part to an object file and write some FFI and a C interface glueing the Python and Haskell worlds together, but that's likely overkill for your needs.
Easier is to just generate the executable with `cabal build`. Then you can use
`cabal list-bin CSVTest` to find out where it has put this executable (it will be something silly like `/home/Dayiz/ConfigV/dist-newstyle/build/x86_64-linux/ghc-9.4.2/ConfigV-0.1.0.0/x/CSVTest/build/CSVTest/CSVTest`). You can copy/symlink this somewhere more convenient, or just note down the filename, say in the Python variable `csvtest_path`. And then

```
subprocess.run([csvtest_path], capture_output=True)
```